# why array splice method outputs a different value when directly printing to console?

Tags: javascript

```js
var listOfUsers = ['Jon', 'Kevin', 'Sam', 'Lapito', 'Marshal'];

console.log(listOfUsers.splice(2, 1, 'Rachel')); // [ 'Sam' ]
```

why Isn't  it printing, // [ 'Jon', 'Kevin', 'Rachel', 'Lapito', 'Marshal' ]

????

Comment: Did you read the documentation for splice? It clearly states why https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value

Comment: The result of `.splice()` is the deleted elements.

Comment: Different value than what?

Answer (score 3):

> why Isn't it printing, // [ 'Jon', 'Kevin', 'Rachel', 'Lapito', 'Marshal' ]

Because that's not what `splice` returns (more info in [the MDN documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)). `splice` returns an array of the elements you removed with the call. It modifies the array you all it on in place.

This may help clarify:

```js
const listOfUsers = ['Jon', 'Kevin', 'Sam', 'Lapito', 'Marshal'];

const returnValue = listOfUsers.splice(2, 1, 'Rachel');

console.log("updated listOfUsers:", listOfUsers);
console.log("return value of splice:", returnValue);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

Side note: If you're just replacing the value of a single element of the array as you are with `splice(2, 1, 'Rachel')`, just use direct assignment:

```
listOfUsers[2] = "Rachel";
```

Answer (score 0):

Splice is performed on the array, so `listOfUsers` will have the items removed, but the method itself returns the removed items.

See the MDN documentation for Array.prototype.splice() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).